# How to label ascending consecutive numbers onto values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column that looks something like this:

```
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
1 <--
0
0
2 <--
0
0
0
3 <--
```

And so forth. I'm not sure where to begin. There about 10,000 rows and I feel like making a if statement might take awhile. How do I achieve this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efficient and concise:

```
s.cumsum()*s
```

```
0    1       
1    0       
2    0       
3    2       
4    0       
5    0       
6    0       
7    3       
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice!  +1  Using a little math here.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Series.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

**Here is an example:**

```
print(df)

   0
0  1
1  0
2  0
3  1
4  0
5  0
6  0
7  1


df['0']=df['0'].cumsum().where(df['0'].ne(0),df['0'])
print(df)

   0
0  1
1  0
2  0
3  2
4  0
5  0
6  0
7  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = pd.Series([1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1])
s.cumsum().mask(s==0, 0)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    2
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` and `cumsum`:

```
df['cum_sum'] = np.where(df.val>0, df.val.cumsum(), 0)
```

output:

```
   val  cum_sum
0    1        1
1    0        0
2    0        0
3    1        2
4    0        0
5    0        0
6    0        0
7    1        3
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
df = {'col1': [1, 0,0,0,1,0,0,1] }

count = 0
col = []
for val in zip(df['col1']):
    if val[0] == 1:
       count+=1
       col.append(count)
    else:
       col.append(val[0])
```

and you get `[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3]`

Comment: You can, but generally should not. `for` loop is slow, not to mention `list().append`.

Answer (score 0):

Only select the rows that are non-zero and replace those values with cumsum

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'col': [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0] })
index=df["col"]!=0
df.loc[index,"col"]=df.loc[index,"col"].cumsum()
print(df)

    col
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    2
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    3
9    0
```